# Javascript: how to check if letter "Y" is vowel or consonant?

Tags: javascript, string, char

Is the letter Y a vowel or a consonant?
Traditionally, A E I O and U are vowels and the rest of the letters are consonants.
However, sometimes the letter Y represents a vowel sound AND sometimes a consonant sound.

How to check if letter "Y" is vowel or consonant in JavaScript?

P.S. For example, I have a word "play" (Y is vowel), or I have a word "year" (Y is consonant). How to check in any word that has "Y" - do "Y" is vowel or consonant?

P.P.S. How to make check using next rules: https://www.woodwardenglish.com/letter-y-vowel-or-consonant/

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in function for that

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What does "check" mean? Like put in a word and it tells you what kind of y is used? Also a Y is always voiced, when does a Y have a consonant sound?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-y-is-sometimes-a-vowel-usage

Comment: "Also a Y is always voiced": Samuel Pepys would like a word.

Comment: For example, I have a word "play" (Y is vowel), or I have a word "year" (Y is consonant). How to check in any word that has "Y" - do "Y" is vowel or consonant?

Comment: Ok, in your link there is a list of simple rules to tell if y is a vowel, now just implement them as code???

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you want to just count vowels, do you need it for password validation, do you want to create the right word wraps, ...? The answer may depend on your usecase.

Comment: Maybe someone have ready-made function

Comment: This check is needed on Numerology test (Soul Urge Number)

Comment: Then you should probably check and implement https://www.worldnumerology.com/blog/numerology-Y-vowel-consonant.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely using the rules in the link you provide as test conditions. Is 'easier' to test the two conditions to be consonant:

1. 'Y' should be at start of the word
2. 'Y' should be at the start of the syllabe

```
// ! Y as a consonant

const vowelRegex = new RegExp(/[aeiou]/gi);

const words = [ 'lawyer', 'beyond', 'annoy', 'tyrant', 'dynamite', 'typical', 'pyramid', 'yes', 'young' ]

const vowelOrConsonant = ( word ) => {
  const isAtStart = word[0] === 'y';
  if( isAtStart ){
    console.log( `${word} Y is consonant.` );
    return;
  }
  // has a letter after the 'y'
  const nextLetter = word[ word.indexOf('y') + 1 ] ?? false;
  if( nextLetter && nextLetter.match(vowelRegex) ){
    console.log( `${word} Y is consonant.` );
    return;
  }
  console.log( `${word} Y is vowel.` );
}

words.forEach( word => {
  vowelOrConsonant(word);
})
```

To make this more accurate you migth need to divide the word into syllabes while adding headaches.